# It is possible to display related posts from same category as the current post?

Tags: categories

We trying portfolio-related posts from the same category it is not working please help me for this issue. The same category-related post not working.

link: http://kalaitamil.com/e21designs/art-work/portfolio-item/aisiri-in-the-battlefeild/

```
<div id="qodef-portfolio-single-related-items">
            <?php
            $params = apply_filters( 'malgre_core_filter_portfolio_single_related_posts_params', array(
                'custom_class'      => 'qodef--no-bottom-space',
                'columns'           => '3',
                'posts_per_page'    => 3,
                'additional_params' => 'id',
                'post_ids'          => $related_posts['items'],
                'layout'            => 'info-below',
                'title_tag'         => 'h5',
                'excerpt_length'    => '100'
            ) );
            
            echo MalgreCorePortfolioListShortcode::call_shortcode( $params ); ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to show more code... ...we have no idea where `$related_posts['items']` is coming from, if it has any data, etc.  Add a `var_dump( $related_posts['items'] );` and see what that spits out.

Comment: Thanks, Tony Djukic. But it is not working

Comment: So there's your issue.  It's how you're building the variable.  If the `var_dump()` is empty that means you're not returning any related posts items.